# solving system of ode using matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I have 9 equations with a time dependent coefficient `g`

```
% MY M file
function dy =tarak(t,y)
G= 3.16;
g =  0.1*exp(-((t-200)/90).^2);
dy=zeros(9,1);
dy(1)=-2*2*y(1)+2*G*y(5)+2*g*y(7);
dy(2)=2*y(1)-2*G*y(5);
dy(3)=2*y(1)-2*g*y(7);
dy(4)=-2*y(4)+g*y(9);
dy(5)=-2*y(5)+G*(y(2)-y(1))+g*y(8);
dy(6)=-2*y(6)-G*y(9);
dy(7)=-2*y(7)+g*(y(3)-y(1))+G*y(8);
dy(8)=-G*y(7)-g*y(5);
dy(9)=G*y(6)-g*y(4);
```

then in command window:

```
[T,Y] = ode45(@tarak,[0 ,500],[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0])
```

where coefficient `G = 3.16` and `g = 0.1*exp(-((t-200)/90).^2)` is a time dependent coefficient and time `t = 0:500`; Initial condition `[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]`.

I'm getting WRONG negative values for output `y(1)`, `y(2)`. Can someone pls try to solve above eqns with `ode45` so that i can compare the results.

Comment: Where do you get that these components have to stay positive? Does that not depend on y(5) and y(7)?

Comment: hi Lutzl , Y(1) ,Y(2), Y(3) are probabilities hence can't be negative , my friend solved above equations in C and getting it right . you too are getting negative value ?

Comment: No, see answer. The code was in python, but that should not matter. You should post a more complete code to see if there are any easily discernable problems.

Comment: dear Lutzl , Thanks ! your plots seems in agreement with the results  i am looking for .do  you used Odeint  in python ?

Comment: Lutzl,I have edited the code in my first post  to give my complete matlab code,kindly have a look

Comment: No, just a simple cookbook implementation of RK4. I've added the code to the answer. Note that python arrays are zero-based, thus the index shift.

Comment: Thanks Sir for valuable info i will go through it ,  is something wrong in my matlab code ? thanks again

Comment: Matlab code is ok but you need to play with the tolerances because your first state has an order of 1e-8 and the default abs tolerance of ode45 is 1e-6.

Comment: No, there is nothing visible that could be wrong. The only thing that is slightly strange is the dot in `g=...).^2)` since `t` in this formula is a scalar, thus there is no need for vectorized operations. But that should not change the numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple application of RK4 I get this picture

[image]

nicely positive, with one strange initial jump in the `y(1)` component. But note the scale, on the whole `y(1)` is rather small. It seems that the system is stiff at this point, so rk45 might have problems, an implicit Runge-Kutta method would be better.

And a zoom of the initial oscillations

[image]

---

### Python code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import exp

def dydt(t,y):
    dy = np.array(y);

    G = 3.16;
    g = 0.1*exp(-((t-200)/90)**2);

    dy[0]=-2*2*y[0]+2*G*y[4]+2*g*y[6];
    dy[1]=   2*y[0]-2*G*y[4];
    dy[2]=   2*y[0]-2*g*y[6];
    dy[3]=  -2*y[3]+  g*y[8];
    dy[4]=  -2*y[4]+  G*(y[1]-y[0])+g*y[7];
    dy[5]=  -2*y[5]-  G*y[8];
    dy[6]=  -2*y[6]+  g*(y[2]-y[0])+G*y[7];
    dy[7]=  -G*y[6]-  g*y[4];
    dy[8]=   G*y[5]-  g*y[3];
    return dy;

def RK4Step(f,x,y,h):
    k1=f(x      , y         )
    k2=f(x+0.5*h, y+0.5*h*k1)
    k3=f(x+0.5*h, y+0.5*h*k2)
    k4=f(x+    h, y+    h*k3)
    return (k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4)/6.0


t= np.linspace(0,500,200+1);
dt = t[1]-t[0];
y0=np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

y = [y0]

for t0 in t[0:-1]:
    N=200;
    h = dt/N;
    for i in range(N):
        y0 = y0 + h*RK4Step(dydt,t0+i*h,y0,h);
    y.append(y0);

y = np.array(y);

plt.subplot(121);
plt.title("y(1)")
plt.plot(t,y[:,0],"b.--")
plt.subplot(122);
plt.title("y(2)")
plt.plot(t,y[:,1],"b-..")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

And in `Matlab`:

```
options = odeset('AbsTol', 1e-12);
[T,Y] = ode45(@tarak, [0, 500], [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0], options);
```

[image]